# hardhat console.log in solidity file outputs nothing

Tags: hardhat

Following hardhat documentation: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/debugging-with-hardhat-network.html

test/Token.js:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Token contract", function () {
  it("Deployment should assign the total supply of tokens to the owner", async function () {
    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");

    const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy();

    const ownerBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
    expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance);
    console.log("Inside Token.js");
  });
});
```

contracts/Token.sol:

```
// Solidity files have to start with this pragma.
// It will be used by the Solidity compiler to validate its version.
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

// This is the main building block for smart contracts.
contract Token {
    // Some string type variables to identify the token.
    // The `public` modifier makes a variable readable from outside the contract.
    string public name = "My Hardhat Token";
    string public symbol = "MHT";

    // The fixed amount of tokens stored in an unsigned integer type variable.
    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000;

    // An address type variable is used to store ethereum accounts.
    address public owner;

    // A mapping is a key/value map. Here we store each account balance.
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    /**
     * Contract initialization.
     *
     * The `constructor` is executed only once when the contract is created.
     */
    constructor() {
        // The totalSupply is assigned to transaction sender, which is the account
        // that is deploying the contract.
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /**
     * A function to transfer tokens.
     *
     * The `external` modifier makes a function *only* callable from outside
     * the contract.
     */
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        console.log("Sender balance is %s tokens", balances[msg.sender]);
        console.log("Trying to send %s tokens to %s", amount, to);
        // Check if the transaction sender has enough tokens.
        // If `require`'s first argument evaluates to `false` then the
        // transaction will revert.
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount, "Not enough tokens");

        // Transfer the amount.
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[to] += amount;
    }

    /**
     * Read only function to retrieve the token balance of a given account.
     *
     * The `view` modifier indicates that it doesn't modify the contract's
     * state, which allows us to call it without executing a transaction.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[account];
    }
}
```

> npx hardhat test

```
Compilation finished successfully


  Token contract
Inside Token.js
    ✓ Deployment should assign the total supply of tokens to the owner (734ms)


  1 passing (737ms)
```

Note that the console.log inside Token.js outputs to console, but the console.log inside Token.sol outputs nothing!

Comment: You are using `console.log` in the `transfer` function, but you are not calling it from the test! It has no chance to print anything.

Answer (score 2):

Since the contract code is running onchain, you'll see the console.log from the chain output, not in your javascript console output.

Answer (score 0):

You have not triggered the transfer function which has the console log statement.

You can put the console log on the constructor and that test will trigger the console log.